# How to export UTF-8 CSV from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, postgresql

I am trying to import data from csv file to PostgreSQL table using PostgreSQL 9.3 version.

**Followed Procedure**:

**Step 1**: Exported data from SQL Server to CSV file.

**Step 2**: In PostgreSQL right click on table the import.

**Step 3**: Selected *.csv file, Format csv and encoding"UTF8" from file option.

**Step 4**: From Misc. Option selected Delimiter ";".

**Step 5**: From Quote Option selected as Quote ' and Escape "

**Step 6**: At last clicked import button to process.

**Note**: But getting the following error message box.

[image]

Comment: Well presumably the CSV file isn't in UTF-8... what makes you think it is? Where did you get it from?

Comment: @Jon Skeet,From SQL Server, I have exported to CSV file.

Comment: There is no "right click" in Postgres. Looks like you're working with pgAdmin III instead?

Comment: Well perhaps you should look in the encoding options when you're exporting?

Comment: @deceze, Yeah! Sorry for that mistake.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Sorry! But I am unable to see where it is.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Is that code page?

Comment: I'd suggest you change your question/focus of research to "How to export UTF-8 CSV from SQL server". You're currently targeting Postgres experts, which may not be familiar with SQL Server.

Comment: Would not surprise me a bit if Microsoft assumes everybody wants cp1251.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the import dialog choose one of the common Windows encodings like `WIN1252`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html#MULTIBYTE-CHARSET-SUPPORTED

Comment: Yeah! I did after your suggestion. But this time getting different error "extra data after last expected column". I checked csv file but there is no extra column. This is really frustrating me.

Comment: @Meem That is a completely different question. Please post another one.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto, Okay. Please checkout my new post.